# Unsigned int bitmask for multiple bit positions

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm teaching myself how to perform bitmasking and bitwise operations in C.

Say I want to have an unsigned integer bitmask of all 0s with a 1 at bits 12 and 23.
I was thinking of calculating the bitmask by setting the variable

```
unsigned int bitmask = 1<<12 & 1<<23;
```

How would I go about calculating the bitmask that has multiple requirements?

Any suggestions and pointers are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You will want to take a look at [**Bit Twiddling Hacks**](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).. It is a good reference for various bitwise operations. Also see [**Hacker's Delight - Chapter 2**](http://hackersdelight.org/basics2.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitwise AND `&` is not the right operator, because it would produce a zero. You need bitwise `|` instead:

```
unsigned int bitmask = 1U<<12 | 1U<<23;
```

If you are looking for a bit mask with multiple bits set, you could use a `for` loop:

```
int bits[] = {1, 5, 13, 28};
unsigned int bitmask = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i != 4 ; i++) {
    bitmask |= 1U << bits[i];
}
```

Comment: I see. For clarification since I am new to bit manipulation,  U signifies that the value of 1 is unsigned?; bitwise OR is needed because bitwise OR is only 0 when both shift values become 0?